# Custom dice roll probability formula

Tags: probability

I want to make an application that gives you the probability of reaching a certain threshold with a number of rolls of special dice. Just to clarify, I am not asking for help on programming, I need a formula to program from.

The variables are

- *d*: the number of dice, all with the sides [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
- *x*: the number the roll needs to reach

I need to work out the probability of rolling *d* dice (of the special type noted above) and getting a total equal to or greater than *x*

Comment: I'd try simulation. Make a virtual die and roll $d$ of them $10000$ times. Then see how many times you get to that total.The alternative is just solving a generic equation which I'm sure you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(t,d)$ be the probability that when you roll $d$ dice, the sum of their numbers is exactly $t.$

Then $p(t,d) = 0$ whenever $t < 0.$
Also $p(t,0) = 0$ when $t > 0,$ but $p(0,0) = 1.$

For $d \geq 0,$ 
$$p(t,d+1) =
\frac16 p(t-1,d) + \frac13 p(t-2,d) + \frac13 p(t-3,d) + \frac16 p(t-4,d).$$

You can use that formula to find any value of $p(t,d)$ recursively.
An efficient way to do this is to compute $p(t,1)$ for every relevant value of $t,$ then $p(t,2)$ for every relevant $t,$ and so forth until you have computed the necessary values of $p(t,d)$ in order to find the probability of rolling at least $x$; that probability is
$$ \sum_{t\geq x} p(t,d).$$

Comment: Note that for $t \in \{d,d+1,\cdots, 4d\}$, $p(t,d)$ is the coefficient of $x^t$ in the polynomial $\phi^d(x)$ below. Exactly the same recursion appears, unsurprisingly, it is essentially a convolution. Do note that $p(t,d)$ is nonzero **iff**  for $t \in \{d,d+1,\cdots, 4d\}$.

Answer (score 1):

For small values of $d$ you could use the following generating function approach:

Let $\phi(x) = {x+ 2 x^2 + 2 x^3 + x^4 \over 6}$, then the
probability that $d$ rolls gives exactly $m$ is the coefficient of
$x^m$ in $\phi^d$, where $m=d,d+1,...,4d$.

To illustrate: If $d=7$ then $\phi^d(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{28} a_k x^k$
where $a={1 \over 6^7}(0 ,
0 ,
0 ,
0 ,
0 ,
0 ,
0 ,
1 ,
14 ,
98 ,
455 ,
1568 ,
4256 ,
9429 ,
17446 ,
27370 ,
36771 ,
42560 ,
42560 ,
36771 ,
27370 ,
17446 ,
9429 ,
4256 ,
1568 ,
455 ,
98 ,
14 ,
1)$.

For example, the probability of getting a sum of exactly $26$
is the coefficient of $x^{26}$ which is ${98 \over 6^7}$.

The probability of the sum being $\ge x$ will be the sum of the coefficients of $x^k$ where $k \ge x$.

There are various ways of computing the polynomial coefficients
depending on what you are trying to achieve.

If you have access to Octave/Matlab, you could try the following:

```
# poly of phi*6, constant term last
f = [1 2 2 1 0];
# 7 rolls
d = 7;
# compute polynomial of (phi*6)^d
p = 1;
for i = 1:d
    p = conv(p, f);
endfor
# scale result so the coefficients are probabilities
# constant term last
p = p/6^d;
```

If not, you could using something like Neville's algorithm to
compute the interpolating polynomial of the points
$\phi^d(0),\cdots, \phi^d(4d)$.

Another way would be to compute the coefficients by multiplying the polynomials $\phi^2 = \phi \cdot \phi$, $\phi^{k+1} = \phi^k \cdot \phi$. This is essentially the convolution of coefficients of
the polynomials being multiplied.

**Aside**:
My original Octave/Matlab code looked something like

```
f = [1 2 2 1 0];
r = roots(f);
d = 7;
v = poly(repmat(r',[1, d]));
v = v/6^d;
```

however, for $d \in \{5,6,7\}$, the `poly` call resulted in
some small imaginary noise. The `conv` call avoids this entirely.

Comment: How small? *d* will always be less than seven.

Comment: The call to `poly` produces an error with both Octave and MATLAB because the matrix argument is not square.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi: My apologies, I will fix momentarily.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi: Thanks for catching that, I gave up on my previous approach as it failed for $d=7$. There were a number of errors in my previous code, I should know not to wing it at this stage!

Comment: Glad to be of some help!